# i am new in unity and it doesnt open projects and i dont understand the error

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine

so about a week ago i changed from windows 7 to pop os(linux) and yesterday i downloaded unity hub from pop store and downloaded the recommended unity editor from it but when i opened a new project the splash screen would open then it disappears then i just open the project a second time and it does the same thing so i just installed unity hub from google for linux and added the previous editor and then when i created a new project it did the splash screen then crashed.then i thought it was a problem with the editor so i dowanloaded 2019 editor for linux from google and used it with both unity hubs and both did the same thing that happened before then when i look at the end of the logs of unity editor i see this:

```
Unloading 2795 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2666.
Total: 25.760335 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.513929 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.212646 ms MarkObjects: 13.867896 ms  DeleteObjects: 11.163769 ms)

[MODES] ModeService[none].Initialize
[MODES] ModeService[none].LoadModes
[MODES] Loading mode Default (0) for mode-current-id-test
[LAYOUT] About to load Library/CurrentLayout-default.dwlt, keepMainWindow=False
GLX Extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_get_proc_address GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_no_config_context GLX_EXT_swap_control GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_INTEL_swap_event GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_MESA_query_renderer GLX_MESA_swap_control GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_OML_sync_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_SGI_make_current_read GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGI_video_sync 
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Unity: ../../src/xcb_io.c:269: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Caught fatal signal - signo:6 code:-6 errno:0 addr:0x3e800041617
Obtained 22 stack frames.
#0  0x007f99d2a351f0 in funlockfile
#1  0x007f99d2875fbb in gsignal
#2  0x007f99d285b864 in abort
#3  0x007f99d285b749 in (Unknown)
#4  0x007f99d286d3d6 in __assert_fail
#5  0x007f99d3ddab2b in _XSend
#6  0x007f99d3ddabce in _XSend
#7  0x007f99d3dddca2 in _XEventsQueued
#8  0x007f99d3dddf8d in _XGetRequest
#9  0x007f99d3dc47c8 in XNoOp
#10 0x007f98c86a61c7 in MesaGLInteropGLXExportObject
#11 0x007f99d253311c in glXDestroyContext
#12 0x005584116823d3 in CreateNativeGLContext(void*)
#13 0x0055840ec543e8 in MakeNewContextGL(GfxDeviceLevelGL, unsigned long, int, int, int, bool, bool, bool, DepthBufferFormat)
#14 0x0055840ec545b9 in SetupGraphicsContextFromWindow(unsigned long, int, int, bool&)
#15 0x0055840d85f1f1 in WindowGLES::Reshape(int, int, DepthBufferFormat, bool)
#16 0x0055840d85f0bb in WindowGLES::WindowGLES(unsigned long, int, int, DepthBufferFormat, bool)
#17 0x0055840d83893e in GfxDeviceGLES::CreateGfxWindow(unsigned long, int, int, DepthBufferFormat, bool)
#18 0x0055841029c1b5 in GUIView::CreateGfxWindow()
#19 0x0055841029fe5b in GUIView::SetWindow(ContainerWindow*)
#20 0x00558410a31bb0 in GUIView_CUSTOM_Internal_SetWindow(ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
#21 0x000000408c605e in (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.GUIView:Internal_SetWindow (UnityEditor.GUIView,UnityEngine.ScriptableObject)
Launching bug reporter
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QObject(0x1dbeeb0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1cef420), current thread is Thread(0x1d9b1d0)
```

i am just a beginner in coding and unity so i dont understand anything in the error message if someone can help me it would be great.

Comment: What version of unity 2019 are you using (full version name)? Have you tried using a different version? I wonder if this was a bug that got fixed since the version you used.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run Unity main process and an Unity process child on different threads. It looks like that the thread where unity is executed changes from 0x1cef420 to 0x1d9b1d0. You have to use a tool that helps you to manage threads (or write a simple thread manager by your own)

Sorry for bad english

Comment: thx for taking your time to answer, i actually deleted the old unity hub and editors because i may have done something wrong with the installation so i followed a tutorial and now it works.